# If both A1 and B1 exist within any single cell within Column C data array, then D1="YES"

Tags: arrays, excel, lookup

Seems like a simple request, however it certainly hasn't been!

If both A1 and B1 exist within any single cell within Column C data array, then D1="YES"

Appreciate any help with this, thanks.

Comment: You get wrong if you think this site is such as "tell me code" site

Answer (score 3):

use ISNUMBER and SEARCH:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1,C1))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1,C1)),"YES","NO")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to solve this:

```
=IF(IF(COUNTIF(C:C,A2)>=1,"1","0")+IF(COUNTIF(C:C,B2)>=1,"1","0")=2,"Yes","No")
```

[image]